Autogyros as air vehicles on a minimal infrastructure forested world
This is a follow-up for Useful aerial recon vehicles for newly colonized worlds (partially since I realized I asked the initial question in a really unclear way).
The first human colony ship has arrived in orbit around their new world (earth-like with life, 0.86g, 1.2 atm, 35% oxygen content in the air). They have better tech than we do, including fusion (which requires large reactor setups), cryogenics and far better batteries, but nothing like anti-gravity or FTL.
They have used satellites and orbital scans from the ship itself to determine the best landing locations, and now send out three shuttles with initial pathfinder/scientist teams. Their goal is to do additional ground-based recon, primarily utilizing drones, though they'll go along themselves as well, to be able to provide field repairs and possibly perform more specialized tasks the drones aren't equipped for if necessary.
In the long term their goal is also to investigate several anomalous areas that are interfering with their orbital scans and seem to block radio communications, making drones unusable there.
However, for this they'll need an easy way to get around. For ground-based transport they'd likely use bikes, but I figure they need a form of light aerial transport as well, both to avoid obstacles like rivers and for easier travel at long distances.
There are two main issues here though. First, a lot of the planet, at least around the landing zones, is highly forested. There are occasional clearings that can be landed at, but nothing that provides much of a runway space. Second, their maintenance capabilities are rather limited. They do have a basic machine shop and spare parts on the shuttles, but they very much want maintenance requirements to be as limited and simple as possible.
The vehicles will be primarily operating in forest and (forested) mountain areas. They don't need to carry much cargo, basically just the bike, a number of smaller drones and a monitoring tablet.
Right now I'm primarily looking at autogyros, which seem like they're relatively efficient and low-maintenance, while also having a very small landing footprint, and with a starting motor and collective pitch on the rotor, can perform jump starts without needing any real take-off area. However, I am uncertain if these are actually the best option, since it's difficult to find information on their actual efficiency vs helicopters. Planes and gliders are obviously more efficient, but to my understanding need a long runway.
Would an autogyro work here, or are there things I'm missing that would cause issues in this case?

Questions asking for best, ideal, plausible, etc. are routinely closed as too story-based. Best for what? Deserts? Forests? High altitude snow pack? Are we carrying one person? A security team? What equipment is needed? How long will they be gone? What kind of fuel are they using? Are we landing on water? Hardpack? Snow? A small meadow? See my point? But perhaps at the top of my list is what research have you done? (Mandatory, see [ask].)

BTW, as you think this through (a) You might consider using our Sandbox. (b) You might remember that we help people build worlds (the rules and infrastructure upon which many stories are written), we don't help people write stories (see [help/on-topic]). Helping you design an aerial recon vehicle is worldbuilding. Telling you which to use in a circumstance is helping you write your story, because every vehicle type will work so long as your story is written to allow it.

It feels like you are trying to shoehorn VTOLs, but you are the author so you can do whatever you want really. It seems unlikely you would want any aerial vehicle investigating a region where radio communication dies off. Some VTOLs can glide but not very well. Planes can glide better but if all electronics dies then if it's a fly by wire plane it's probably screwed as well. It seems unlikely an expedition would design a vehicle to counter the anomaly if they don't know about it, wouldn't generic (modular) vehicles be most used to colonise many planets?

@JBH Sorry, thought I made that clear in the question, will edit it in. Talking about a single-seater vehicle capable of carrying a small amount of gear (bike, some drones and monitoring tablet) in an old-growth forest environment. So something with good range and a small landing/take-off footprint. For research, I've been primarily looking at autogyros, which I think fit the criteria and has an interesting vibe, but I'm uncertain how practical they are, and there's not a lot of info on them aside from a few hobbyist forums, which don't seem to be able to agree on how efficient they are.

Flying a small shuttle unsupported into an anomalous zone that's already downed at least one drone is giving me strong "first victim in a horror film" vibes. If it were me, I'd at least want a friendly camp somewhere in running distance before setting foot in that place.

Autogiros are primitive and not versatile, why not use something more up to date and in line with the rest of the technology that your culture has developed? Eg. YouTube search for vertical takeoff car.

you don't want to use aircraft to land in forests, nothing that can carry a human is going to land in anything but the sparsest wild forest unless you can clear your landing area in advance. you want a land vehicle or watercraft. the closest you can get is aircraft that land on water and hope for lakes to land on,  but then you need to do some swimming.

Why not consider what is currently used in such situations?: STOL fix wing, with many using floats. Also if it isn't withing a short distance of a navigable river they aren't extracting that resource anytime soon.

There's a reason autogyros lost out to helicopters and that is that they lack a lot of the benefits while having most of the disadvantages.
They can't take off and land vertically, they are almost as hard to control as helicopters (there's a very good reason you need special training to fly either, even if you already are a trained aircraft pilot), they're mechanically about as complex, and they tend to have very limited carrying capacity (why you mostly find them in hobbyist circles, where that's irrelevant).
Given the level of technology of your colonists, building helicopters would be a lot more logical for them. Basically they can use the wood and resin of the trees to create the structural components of the helicopter. (the resin can likely be used as the basis for glue, allowing the creation of plywood and maybe even crude composite materials). Fibers of some sort can be fashioned into control cables if nothing else is available, and all you'd need to find a source of are reasonably small engines (those could be carried in the colony ship for the first batch, plus maybe the machinery for the industrial infrastructure to build more of them once sources of metals and fuel are found (oh yes, you need fuel as well, obviously. Though electrical motors could work for short distances, but then you'd need advanced battery technology and some sort of power station to charge those batteries).
Now you have everything you'd have with autogyros without the need for any runways. A clearing in a forest will do.
And you have helicopters similar to those used in the later stages of WW2 and into the early stages of the Korean war.

If there are no clearings, then even a helicopter cannot land.
If you have a continuous canopy to your forest, you can use something like the Canopy Raft. This is a large, light platform that can be placed on top of the trees. It can be placed there by airships or helicopters. Once people have got to the ground, they can then create a clearing for other aircraft.
The Autogyro is a strange, niche vehicle. It is effectively a slow, light aircraft with a low stall speed. You need a runway, but only a short one. However, you can make a rough runway that will be good enough for a light aircraft with a tractor. The runway was also a useful navigation aid because it could be easily spotted when you were in the air. As flights got longer, and aircraft got faster, the autogyro got left behind. It did have uses at the beginning of WW2 for submarine spotting, where the low speed was an advantage.
Autogyros did not really get pushed out by helicopters. A helicopter is a much more complicated thing.
Does your forest have rivers? You can land on a river. You can send in a boat. That is how explorers used to get in.
